# Flyspell without a mouse

Tags: emacs, flyspell

How can I add a word to the dictionary in flyspell without using a mouse? I know, I can use the regular ispell.el binding M-$ and and go through the menu for that, however, this needs multiple keystrokes.

Is it possible to bind the "Save Word" functionality from the flyspell pop-up window to to a single key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you get to choose options - press <kbd>i</kbd> that should add it into your local dictionary (well, does for me anyway :)).

Thorough examination of ispell.el shows that there's no special function to do it, but you could have one of you own:

```
(defun save-ispell-word (word)
  (interactive "sA word you want to add to dictionary ")
  (ispell-send-string (concat "*" word "\n"))
  (setq ispell-pdict-modified-p '(t)))
```

But it will work only in ispell minor mode.